# Find a $C^\infty$ diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto $U$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$. Find a $C^\infty$ diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto $U$.

So I need to find some $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow U$ such that $f$ is $C^\infty$ and so is $f^{-1}$. So I am trying to think of trig functions. So my thought is that $f(\frac{2}{\pi}sin(x)arctan(y),\frac{2}{\pi}cos(x)arctan(y))$ would work, but I don't think I can find an inverse for such a function. Does this example work? and if not how can I find such a diffeomorphism?

Comment: $ f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $, $ f(z) = \frac{z}{1-|z|^2} $ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: $U$ is a set of tuples, so $f(x,y)=(x,y)/(1-(x,y)^2)$?

Comment: Not exactly. It's $f(x,y)=(x,y)/(1-|(x,y)|)^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(v) = \frac{v}{1+\|v\|}$$ works in the direction you want. To find the inverse, note that $f(v)$ and $v$ are parallel, and examine the expression for $\|f(v)\|$ in terms of $\|v\|$.

Comment: How do you prove that $f$ is infinitly many times differentiable in the origin? It seems non obviuos to me